# How to read info-documentation as pdf?

Tags: gnu, texinfo

(Almost) all GNU programs ship info documentation that is viewable with `info <topic>`. This uses a TUI for displaying the documentation. I dislike this, since it is hardly readable. Given the `.texi`-files, on can also generate a pdf-file from the documentation, but this makes it neccessary to manually download the source package. Is there a way to generate pdf-documentation from the `.info`-files?

*Please move this question to superuser.com if appropriate.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use other readers like tkinfo or pinfo. Or just use your browser going to https://gnu.org/software/program-name. I haven't found nothing to convert info files to pdf.